# xslt sorting by author in different places within xml structure

Tags: xslt, sorting

I'm trying to sort a bibliography by author name with XSLT. However the last name of the author appears in different places with the xml structure depending on what kind of text it is (book, journal, etc).

Here's the data:

```
<biblStruct type="book" xml:id="Swanson2002">
<monogr>
  <title>Universities, academics and the Great Schism</title>
  <author>
    <forename>R. N</forename>
    <surname>Swanson</surname>
  </author>
  <imprint>
    <pubPlace>Cambridge</pubPlace>
    <biblScope type="vol">12</biblScope>
    <publisher>Cambridge Univ Pr</publisher>
    <date>2002</date>
    <note type="accessed">2012-07-06 18:34:53</note>
    <note type="url">http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&amp;lr=&amp;id=9AUE425_1xYC&amp;oi=fnd&amp;pg=PR8&amp;dq=Swanson,+Univiersities+Plaoul&amp;ots=EdkhHvSExW&amp;sig=tFOJKFi2myNWhkR_Rl4XE-cQcSc</note>
  </imprint>
</monogr>
<note type="tags">
  <note type="tag">Petrus Plaoul</note>
</note>
 <idno type="ISBN">0521522269</idno>
</biblStruct>
<biblStruct type="journalArticle" xml:id="Maier1958">
<analytic>
  <title>Zu einigen Sentenzenkommentaren des XIV Jahrunderts</title>
  <author>
    <forename>A.</forename>
    <surname>Maier</surname>
  </author>
</analytic>
<monogr>
  <title>Archivum franciscanum historicum</title>
  <imprint>
    <biblScope type="vol">51</biblScope>
    <biblScope type="pp">405-409</biblScope>
    <date>1958</date>
  </imprint>
</monogr>
<note type="tags">
  <note type="tag">Hard Copy Obtained</note>
</note>
</biblStruct>
<biblStruct type="bookSection" xml:id="Kaluza1995">
<analytic>
  <title>Les débuts de l'Albertisme tardif (Paris et Cologne)</title>
  <author>
    <forename>Zenon</forename>
    <surname>Kaluza</surname>
  </author>
</analytic>
<monogr>
  <title>Albertus Magnus und der Albertismus</title>
  <imprint>
    <pubPlace>Leiden</pubPlace>
    <biblScope type="pp">207-295</biblScope>
    <publisher>Brill</publisher>
    <date>1995</date>
  </imprint>
</monogr>
</biblStruct>
```

Here's my XSLT template

```
 <xsl:template match="tei:listBibl">
    <xsl:for-each select="./tei:biblStruct">
        <xsl:sort select="./tei:monogr/tei:author/tei:surname"/>
    </xsl:for-each/>
 </xsl:template/>
```

Currently this only sorts the entries for `@type=monogr`

I also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
<xsl:sort select="./tei:monogr/tei:author/tei:surname or     ./tei:analytic/tei:author/tei:surname"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me as if either

```
<xsl:sort select=".//author/surname"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:sort select="./*/author/surname"/>
```

would do the job

You don't want to use an "or" operator, which always returns a boolean result, but if necessary you could use the "union" operator (|):

```
<xsl:sort select="monogr/author/surname | analytic/author/surname"/>
```

which in 2.0 can be shortened to

```
<xsl:sort select="(monogr|analytic)/author/surname"/>
```